# How to put default delete button and disclosure button in uitable view?

Tags: iphone

I want to default delete button and disclosure button in uitable view how it possble?

Answer (score 4):

1. To add disclosure button in your data source implementation of `-cellForRowAtIndexPath` method add

   [cell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton];
2. To show delete button set tableView.editing property to YES and implement delegate's `editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath` method and return appropriate editing style (None, Insert or delete) for each cell.

Look in docs for more details